# Are original (album art) filenames encoded within an MP3 file?

Tags: mp3, tags, flac, album-art

I would like to ask if embedded album art inside `.mp3` or `.flac` files has a filename. For example if the image was `art.jpg` will it have the same name inside the song?

Comment: I checked my flac and mp3 files and nope Artwork 0,Artwork 1, and etc.

Comment: @daves: You´ve asked and I answered you but I didn´t get any response?

Answer (score 0):

Like you wrote: the album art are embedded into mp3 so it will not have a file name. They will embedded MIME encoded. If you want to know more about embedded images into mp3 please read the [specification](http://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#Attached_picture).